# Get generic type container name

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, inference

How to extract "upper type" from a generic type, and use it to wrap one more generic parameter? For example:

```
type Cont<C, T> = ...

let a: Cont<Promise<number>, string>;

// add string to number put in Promise<...>
// Promise<number, *> <---- string
// Promise<number | string>
//
// a should be of type Promise<number|string>

let b: Cont<[string], boolean>;

// add boolean to string put in Array<...>
// Array<string, *> <---- boolean
// Array<string | boolean>
//
// b should be of type Array<string|boolean> i.e. (string|boolean)[]
```

After hours of racking my brain with infer, I totally give up.

Comment: Don't know if this you want but check once.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AHgCoD4oF4qoNwBQBANhMFAIYBcsiKA2gAoBOcAtgJYDOEyCArmwBGEZugA0ULsGYcEAcwC66QgHpVlKQAs4-YgBMoIqHABmUUJCgt23XgOGiAPtNkL0RUuSE14SZPSucvKSQnBwpBQIymoaQtq6BkbQZhbg0ACCzMwUIMhBCk5hERBRmBwAdBAVUAAUBfJF4ZEIAJT0ikA

Comment: no, it's not that

Comment: Do you mean `string[]`  when you say `[string]`? They are different types.  I'm going to assume you mean `string[]`.  TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal; the name you use for a type doesn't matter.  So there's nothing about `Promise<number>` or `Array<string>` or `Foo<Bar>` that can be used to pull out `number` or `string` or `Bar` from those.  Unless you want to can enumerate a list of cases that `Cont` can handle (e.g., `Promise` and `Array` but nothing else), you can't do this.  What is the use case anyway?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so you need to know all possible, as you call it "upper types", applicable in your scenario. For instance if they consist of `Promise` and `Array` it could be written like that:

```
type Cont<T, T2> = T extends Array<infer AT>
  ? Array<AT | T2>
  : T extends Promise<infer PT>
    ? Promise<PT | T2>
    : never;

type A = Cont<Promise<number>, string>; // Promise<string | number>
type B = Cont<string[], boolean> // Array<string | boolean>
```

The key language feature here is conditional types and [inferring within conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).